# Limit findAll() results

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm storing some information in a MySQL database in two separate tables. I use one class to create and populate both tables. I then use a simple scrip to get this information and populate a Handsontable.

I now want to retrieve **some** variables as opposed to all of them from the class file, but I'm finding this fairly hard; I can retrieve all of them using the .findall() method, but this (unsurprisingly) retrieves all the variables.

Getting the information from class file.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/result", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String defaultView(Model model) {
    Iterable<Request> request = requestRepository.findAll();      
    model.addAttribute("requests", request);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(request);
    System.out.println(json);
    model.addAttribute("jsonProducts", json);
    return "form/result";
}
```

The Handsontable file (if it helps)

```
var data = ${jsonProducts}; 
    var ht = new Handsontable(dataTable, {
        data: data,    
        startRows: data.length,
        readOnly: true,
        maxCols: 7,
        colHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: ["Id", "Problem", "Solution", "Deadline", "Type", "Status", "Developer"],            
    });
```

So my question is: Can I limit the results (instead of using findAll() method) from my class file that stores the MySQL data?

If I provided a poor description of my problem or have failed to supply enough information, please tell me so.

---

Sorry for an confusion I have caused, I will try to explain what I need in a bit more detail.

When I use the findAll() method, the Handsontable looks like so...
[Handsontable output using findAll()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DBdf.png)

I would like to only retrieve the first 7 columns and ignore the last 3 (H, I J).
So I was wondering if I could some how retrieve just the first 7 columns or is it possible to hide the last 3?

Once again, sorry for any confusion, this is the first question I've asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: your question doesnt make much sense - you're showing some sort of data retrieval but ask about "variables from a class file" ... are you somehow confused? If you want to retrieve "variables" from a CLASS FILE you will need to fire up some sort of bytecode-interpreter but that wont get you anywhere regarding your question ...

Comment: @specializt thank you for responding so quickly and sorry for any confusion I have caused. I have updated the question, please let me know if it makes more sense

Comment: you really need to read this entire document : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/. Its somewhat mandatory if you want to use spring data JPA. Even better and also necessary : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Spring Data JPA 1.7.0 (Evans release train) or higher** to get limited number of values from DB.

Then you can use:

```
findTop10BySomething(); //you need to specify Something
```

Hope that helps and that was something that you wanted to achieve.

Comment: im guessing the spring framework is too complex for him right now - and your answer wont even work without massive changes in his data model.

Comment: the question is incomplete, that was little more than a guess.

Comment: you're right - the `Model` class and `@RequestMapping` are pretty common in spring MVC, he might already be using spring, good catch!

Comment: @m.aibin thank you for your answer. Sadly I am very new to this kind of thing, I'm not 100% how implement it. Could you give me another example?